# return in try block vs return after the block

Tags: java, return, try-catch

I have a try statement in a small static method, is there a best practice as to where I should return from?

```
try {
    mightThrow();
    return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
}
```

or after,

```
try {
    mightThrow();
} catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Functionally, these *should* preform identically, is there actually a bytecode difference? Performance wise, are they the **exact** same?

Or is one just preferred over the other? Which and why?

Comment: "*is there actually a bytecode difference?*" Why don't you check the bytecode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't heard of an actual best practice in this matter, but you often see that when methods use premature returns, the returns `true` case is at the bottom, e.g.

```
public bool canReadFile(path) {
  if (!fileExists(path))  
    return false;

  if (!fileIsReadable(file))
    return false;

  ...
  return true;
}
```

Because of that, I'd suggest you follow this practice for try/catch blocks. It also makes it quicker to see what the "expected" return value is.

In regards to the bytecode, then yes, there is indeed a difference. I made a quick sample program

```
class TryBlock {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a();
        b();
    }

    public static boolean a() {
        try {
            System.out.println("A");
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean b() {
        try {
            System.out.println("B");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Then compiled it and inspected the bytecode

```
$ javac TryBlock.java; javap -c TryBlock
Compiled from "TryBlock.java"
class TryBlock {
  TryBlock();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       1: invokespecial #1                  
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       // Method a:()Z
       0: invokestatic  #2                  
       3: pop
       // Method b:()Z
       4: invokestatic  #3                  
       7: pop
       8: return

  public static boolean a();
    Code:
       // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       0: getstatic     #4                  
       // String A
       3: ldc           #5                  
       // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       5: invokevirtual #6                  
       8: iconst_1
       9: ireturn
      10: astore_0
      11: iconst_0
      12: ireturn
    Exception table:
       from    to  target type
           0     9    10   Class java/lang/Exception

  public static boolean b();
    Code:
       // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       0: getstatic     #4                  
       // String B
       3: ldc           #8                  
       // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       5: invokevirtual #6                  
       8: goto          14
      11: astore_0
      12: iconst_0
      13: ireturn
      14: iconst_1
      15: ireturn
    Exception table:
       from    to  target type
           0     8    11   Class java/lang/Exception
}
```

So is there a performance difference? While I haven't tested, my bet is there won't be anything noticeable. On top of that, this will hardly be the bottleneck of your application.

Comment: Great answer. One question: **How did you compiled and inspected the bytecode ?**

Comment: As is in my answer, I used `javac` followed by `javap`.

Answer (score 2):

To me this is more a semantics and readability issue.

If your `return true` is at the end of the segment outside of the `try/catch` block, it means this function is supposed to return true value unless anything bad happened in between which interrupts the normal flow.

Instead if the `return true` is at the end of the `try` block, it means the function should only return true if all the attempts in the try block succeeded.

This difference in byte code is more or less neglectable; and I agree with @kba this is more a style issue. Many `return` statement at different places inside deeply embedded `if` blocks would usually be confusing; so it's a good practice to make your code less complex. I.e.

1. Use flat blocks than deep embed where possible
2. Carry less state to another code segment and/or an inner `if`, `for` or `try` block
3. Use less state and flow controlling variable
4. Use less statement like `return` or `go` because they are more or less a compulsory change of the logic flow.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Return is always set false for any type of exception. This may not be the case you will be expecting. May be some of the unexpected exceptions would cause a false value to be returned. So not a good standard way of returning in catch